# C++ Library to render ODF documents?

Tags: c++, odf

I am unable to find any open source libraries to render ODF documents using C++. I found ODKit suporting Java and AODL for .NET C#.

Does any one have any idea or provide me any pointers.

Comment: Hi,

Perhaps, I am unable to find now any ODF rendering library supporting the latest ODF specification in any language say Java, Perl, Py, etc.

Question: How do I write an application to render my .odt files ?

Comment: You want to render it -- in what sense?  Display?  Obtain a bitmap image of the document?

Answer (score 4):

[I found a Qt source to parse ODF.](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/OpenDocument+format+Reader%2BWriter+odt?content=80650) [Qt already has built in ODF writer.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtextdocumentwriter.html)

Answer (score 3):

KOffice supports ODF and is written in C++. I suspect they may have solved whatever it is you are trying to solve. http://www.koffice.org

Comment: Hey Ryan. Well, KDE (or KOffice) is a huge desktop development framework for *nix platform. However, I am unable to find any modules related to ODF rendering en all.

Comment: KOffice runs on Windows and Mac as well. Anything to do with rendering may be deep inside, as it's a core functionality: http://www.koffice.org/developer/apidocs/

Comment: True. In other words, lot of re-factoring/#defines has to be practiced on KOffice code to extract rendering functionality alone. Well, I believed open source meant open design...however, design is through source which makes it tough to re-factor or build a render engine in days. Thanks by the way for he answers. What about any  lightweight ODF viewers in LGPL , I may use. Any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the most elegant solution but OpenOffice itself is capable of rendering and the [OOoSDK](http://download.openoffice.org/sdk/index.html) can be used from C++ as seen [here for writer](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Programming_OooWriter) and [here for spreadsheet](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=89285).

Answer (score 0):

There is none. You're better AODL or any of the other libs available (python, perl, java, etc) and doing a binding to it

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

However, these all are not RENDER libraries. They allow you to manipulate, create or modify ODF documents but do not have any extensions for rendering the ODF document in GUI windows/frames. I checked all examples of AODL http://odftoolkit.org/AODL-Examples

Answer (score 0):

KOffice can be an idea, but if I just want to display an odt file in a nice Qt QWidget, but I don't want to depends on DBus and a lots of Kde feature.

The Idea is to take a look a Flake and KoText libs as Thomas Zanders says on [this Forum](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=96&t=84375).