# Libraries for .odt formatting

Tags: c++, c, odt

Are there any C/C++ libraries available that can be used in creating, loading and saving files in .odt-format?

Alternatively, where can I find tutorial-like information on implementing .odt(/ODF) specifications?

Comment: Duplicate: [C++ Library to render ODF documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083802/c-library-to-render-odf-documents)

Comment: @PeterWood: sorry, no. rendering != creating, loading and saving.

Comment: @PeterWood: I did not consider rendering to be a problem if the create/load/save problem can be solved, but thanks for the link - I'm going through the answers there.

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2619161/15161; now it begs the question: what is the use of a standard if it is so difficult to actually use it?

Comment: @slashmais Flexibility can be perceived as complexity. If you don't need the flexibility, create a template ODT and just fill in the content as needed. As mentioned, there exist XML parsers to actually handle IO. ODT isn't a plaintext file, so some complexity/difficulty is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site: [OASIS OpenDocument Essentials](http://books.evc-cit.info/odbook/book.html) seems to cover the problem, including howto-examples and shortcuts.
It's quite nicely done and easy to follow.

> Flexibility can be perceived as complexity. If you don't need the
>   flexibility, create a template ODT and just fill in the content as
>   needed. As mentioned, there exist XML parsers to actually handle IO.
>   ODT isn't a plaintext file, so some complexity/difficulty is expected.
>   – Ioan

From the link:

> The Virtues of Cheating
>
> As you begin to work with OpenDocument files, you may want to write a
>   program that constructs a document with some feature that isn’t
>   explained in this book—this is, after all, an “essentials” book. Just
>   start OpenOffice.org or KOffice, create a document that has the
>   feature you want, unpack the file, and look for the XML that
>   implements it. To get a better understanding of how things works,
>   change the XML, repack the document, and reload it. Once you know how
>   a feature works, don’t hesitate to copy and paste the XML from the
>   OpenDocument file into your program. In other words, cheat. It worked
>   for me when I was writing this book, and it can work for you too!